# Gui program increments but does not decrement

Tags: java, user-interface

This code is supposed to both increment or decrement based on which button is pressed, however, only increment works. Here's a tidbit of the code because I am not allowed to post the whole code:

Author Haris Irshad:

```
   Listener listenNow = new Listener();
    decrement.addActionListener(listenNow);
    increment.addActionListener(listenNow);
    panel.add(decrement);
    panel.add(increment);
    panel.add(label);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new IncrementDecrement();
}

private class Listener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent anyEvent) {
        if (anyEvent.getSource() == decrement) {
            info = label.getText();
            dec = Integer.parseInt(info);
            dec = dec - 1;
            info = Integer.toString(dec);
            label.setText(info);
        } else if (anyEvent.getSource() == increment) {
            info = label.getText();
        }
        dec = Integer.parseInt(info);
        dec = dec + 1;
        info = Integer.toString(dec);
        label.setText(info);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I found the problem. The brace was incorrectly placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a moment to look at your logic...

```
// If decrement action...
if (anyEvent.getSource() == decrement) {
    // Decrement value...
    info = label.getText();
    dec = Integer.parseInt(info);
    dec = dec - 1;
    info = Integer.toString(dec);
    label.setText(info);
// If increment action...
} else if (anyEvent.getSource() == increment) {
    // Get the text...???
    info = label.getText();
}

// And then increment the value when all else is done...
dec = Integer.parseInt(info);
dec = dec + 1;
info = Integer.toString(dec);
label.setText(info);
```

So basically, when you try and decrement the value, you do actually decrease it, but immediately increment it again...

Try moving the last piece of code into the `else-if` statement, for example...

```
if (anyEvent.getSource() == decrement) {
    info = label.getText();
    dec = Integer.parseInt(info);
    dec = dec - 1;
    info = Integer.toString(dec);
    label.setText(info);
} else if (anyEvent.getSource() == increment) {
    info = label.getText();
    dec = Integer.parseInt(info);
    dec = dec + 1;
    info = Integer.toString(dec);
    label.setText(info);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent anyEvent) {
        if (anyEvent.getSource() == decrement) {
            info = label.getText();
            dec = Integer.parseInt(info);
            dec = dec - 1;
            info = Integer.toString(dec);
            label.setText(info);
        } else if (anyEvent.getSource() == increment) {
            info = label.getText();
            dec = Integer.parseInt(info);
            dec = dec + 1;
            info = Integer.toString(dec);
            label.setText(info);

        }
        // These are causing the issue. These should be part of else if (anyEvent.getSource() == increment) { 
        /*dec = Integer.parseInt(info);
        dec = dec + 1;
        info = Integer.toString(dec);
        label.setText(info);*/
        // Coz of above every time this method is called it will result in increment.
    }
```

Comment: This is correct. But I will choose the other answer because he has helped me out before.

Comment: No issues.I appreciate your concern.